# Rails Acts As Messageable setting up Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller

I'm trying to use [acts as message able gem](https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable) and I'm following their example [controller](https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable/wiki/Example-controller)

**SOLVED See Answer**

I keep getting this error **undefined method `send_message' for nil:NilClass** when trying to send a message in the view

How should I adjust my code?
Thanks

**View (Form)**

```
            <%= simple_form_for ActsAsMessageable::Message.new, :url => messages_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :to, value: @gear.user.email %>
                <%= f.input :body %>
                <%= f.input :topic %>
                <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn' %>
            <% end %>
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  acts_as_messageable :table_name => "messages",                         # default 'messages'
                      :required   => [:topic, :body],                     # default [:topic, :body]
                      :class_name => "ActsAsMessageable::Message",       # default "ActsAsMessageable::Message",
                      :dependent  => :nullify                            # default :nullify

end
```

**Messages Controller**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @message = ActsAsMessageable::Message.new
  end

  def create
    @to = User.find_by_email(params[:acts_as_messageable_message][:to])
    current_user.send_message(@to, params[:acts_as_messageable_message][:topic], params[:acts_as_messageable_message][:body])
  end
end
```

**Development Log**

```
Started POST "/messages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-15 07:23:40 -0600
Processing by MessagesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OqaDOP6PldbFVXWPZyijn+887Ym/fDsU0oqzVrL0rQA=", "acts_as_messageable_message"=>{"to"=>"xyz@test.com", "body"=>"test", "topic"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Create Message"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'xyz@test.com' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `send_message' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:29:in `create
```

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it working. The problem ultimately was the gem was using the User model and was expecting the controller to be the User controller not another controller called "Messages". So I simply moved my actions into my Users controller, added the routes and changed the view path, and it now works. @Alex.Bullard thanks for the help.

I'm posting my edits below:

**Controller Change**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json
  def new_message
    @message = ActsAsMessageable::Message.new
  end

  def create_message
    @to = User.find_by_email(params[:acts_as_messageable_message][:to])
    current_user.send_message(@to, params[:acts_as_messageable_message][:topic], params[:acts_as_messageable_message][:body])
    redirect_to :back, notice: "Message sent to Owner"
  end

end
```

**View**

```
            <%= simple_form_for ActsAsMessageable::Message.new, :url => create_message_users_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :to, value: @gear.user.email %>
                <%= f.input :body %>
                <%= f.input :topic %>
                <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn' %>
            <% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
  resources :users, :except => [ :create, :new ] do
     get "new_message", :on => :collection
     post "create_message", :on => :collection
     resources :store
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error message and provided code seems like your params obj is not formated like you think. Give `params[:acts_as_messageable_message]` a try instead of `[:message]`. If that doesn't work check the log to see what is being passed in as params.

Comment: I made changes as suggested. Threw a different error. See my edits